# How can I get Website Data by Reading Div-Contents of them

Tags: php, xss, file-get-contents, cross-site, php-include

I know about API's but i'm looking for a more universal solution.

With this Code I get the DIV-Construction of a foreign Website.

```
 $url = 'http://www.Abc.de';
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        echo $response;
```

but the Javascript doesent fill content.
It also doesent works with include.
Is there a Possibility to read Data about the Browser? Like an Eye do?

Comment: It is not a file you are including. Index.php is a file. http://whatever.com is a URL that will auto-load index.php or index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for include you must enable `allow_url_include = On` in php.ini and if you want to find `div` in page use `HTML DOM`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('url');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div) {
    $divs[]=$div->nodeValue;
}
print_r($divs);
```

good luck